# Save output data in image format

Tags: php, mysql, image, drupal, google-api

I am saving the data as jpeg file but it is not saving properly.

```
$file=  drupal_http_request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDGsEo0x-oqsIDVn0EaTx6mN1BMXkAhZDs');
   $handle=fopen("/public/image.jpeg",'w');
   fwrite($handle,$file->data);
   fclose($handle);
```

The output : $file->data is :"    IHDRddpâ•TIDATxÚílUåÇkbæ....."

Comment: What are you trying to save in an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself the headache - use [`system_retrieve_file()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7)

```
$result = system_retrieve_file($url, 'public://image.jpeg');
```

I imagine your current code isn't working because you're not using a proper URI to the public folder, but you might may as well use the API where available.

Comment: The url which I am using is the url of google photo place whose response is an image.Now I want to save it in my drive,so i created a jpeg file and trying to write content on it but its not working.

Comment: ok...presumably you've at least tried the code I posted? What happened? What errors did you get if it's not working? By the way the same method has worked for me hundreds of times so if it's not working, you probably haven't read the documentation thoroughly

Comment: $url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDGsEo0x-oqsIDVn0EaTx6mN1BMXkAhZDs';

    $file=  drupal_http_request($url);
   $handle=fopen('public://image_file.jpeg','w');
   //system_retrieve_file($url, 'public://image1.jpeg');
   fwrite($handle,$file->data);
   fclose($handle);

Comment: I tried this code, I was able to save the image using fopen but system_retrieve_file is not saving the file still.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report on Drupal.org then. As I say, I've used that function without problem hundreds of times. I've used it once today already in a real world project. If you've got it working with `fopen`, though, just use that if you're working to a deadline

Comment: Thanks,that I am also wondering why its not working its a a signle line command.But I will try to make it work for future :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead [file](http://php.net/fopen) function you can use [copy](http://php.net/copy) like this:

```
try{        
copy($source, $destination);
}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "<br/>\n unable to copy '$fileName'. Error:$e";

}
```